# how to get an HTML element value in liquid?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

```
<span id="product_wished_id">value</span>
```

I want to get that value and store it in liquid variable.

for example : {% assign myvalue = ? %}

Is there no way to getting an html element value and store it in liquid variable? to perform if else statement in liquid?

Answer (score 2):

Liquid operates on server-side, so it does not have access to your client-side, i.e your DOM, due to which it is not possible to use Liquid alone to extract HTML values and store it in a Liquid variable.

If you need to perform client-side operations like extracting values from HTML elements, then use those values in conditional statements, then you can use JavaScript.